# Tk Text widget - get new size in lines and chars

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

When you create a Tk Text widget you can specify its size as `-height` and `-width` measured in lines and characters in the default font.

If the widget later gets resized, I want to read the new size in lines and chars, but I can't see how.  I'm not changing the font at all.  Binding to the `<Configure>` event will report the new size in pixels in %h and %w.  Doing `cget -height` or `cget -width` just reports the originally configured line and char sizes.  Is there a way to detect the new size in lines and characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the width in pixels and make an estimate:

```
set width [expr {round($pwidth/[font measure TkTextFont 0])}]
```

Height would be something like:

```
set height [expr {round($pheight/[font metrics TkTextFont -linespace])}]
```

Substitute `TkTextFont` with the actual font that is used.